# GDB run as subprocess stops parent process after receiving a 'kill -9'

Tags: python, linux, gdb, subprocess, kill

I am running automated tests in python by running a script that runs a batched instance of GDB.  If the output meets certain conditions I kill the pid of gdb so I can launch a new instance of GDB.  I am running GDB only to log backtraces in case of segfaults.  My issue is that killing the GDB instance in the script or by kill on a terminal results in my script being "Stopped".

Is there a way to send a kill signal to a GDB subprocess without it Stopping my parent process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running GDB only to log backtraces in case of segfaults

Alternatives:

1. `glibc`'s `catchsegv` / `libSegFault.so`.
2. [`segv_handler`](http://samba.org/ftp/unpacked/junkcode/segv_handler/)
3. Install a handler for those signals you're interested in (`SIGSEGV`,
   `SIGABRT`, etc.) which launches `gstack` or `gdb`, attaches to itself and dumps the relevant trace.